# Making a recursive function in php

Tags: php, recursion

Im trying to make a recursive function build an array of data from the database.

This function takes looks into the database and gets the group names and ids and puts the id's in the helper array and the names in a different array.

```
private function Groups()
{
  $helperArray = array();
  $this->grouplist = array();
  $functionRun = 0;

  $query = "SELECT GroupName, Groups.idGroup  
            FROM Groups
            INNER JOIN Members
            ON Groups.idGroup = Members.idGroup
            WHERE Members.idMember = ? ";

            //prepare query and execute
  if($stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query))
  {

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $this->id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($GroupName, $idGroup);
    $stmt->store_result();
    $groupNum = $stmt->num_rows;

    while ($stmt->fetch()) 
    {
       $helperArray[] = $idGroup;
       $this->grouplist[] = array("Group ID"=>$idGroup,"Group Name"=>$GroupName);

    }

  }

  if ($functionRun > $groupNum) 
  {
      echo 'function done';


  }

  else 
  {
    $this->getGroups($functionRun, $helperArray, $helperVariable);
  }

}
```

This function selects all the members in a each group that is in the helper array and adds them to the group list array. This function runs the same amount as the number of groups. It increments the functionRan variable each time it runs.

```
private function getGroups($functionRun, $helperArray, $helperVariable)
{


  $query = "SELECT Users.Username
             FROM Members
             INNER JOIN Users
             ON Members.idMember = Users.idUsers
             WHERE idGroup = ? ";

  $helperVariable = $helperArray[$functionRun];

  if($stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query))
  {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $helperVariable);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($username);

  }

     while ($stmt->fetch()) 
     {

       array_push($this->grouplist[$functionRun], $username);

     }

$functionRun++;

$this->Groups();
}
```

The error i get is

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /webroot/signin.php on line 170

Comment: Which function is line 170 in - since you have two `fetch` statements, it will help to know.

Comment: So under some circumstance, `$stmt` doesn't get prepared and executed.  `echo $this->connection->error;` to find out why in an `else`  block after the `prepare()`.

Comment: when i take out $this->Groups();

Comment: line 170 is in getGroups function

Answer (score 0):

A Problem you probably have. (You are not giving line information or filename. So I can't know if this is your problem, only that it may be).

In `getGroups()`, The if and the while are not in the same block.

You have.

```
if($stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query))
  {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $helperVariable);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($username);

  }

     // Outside the if block
     while ($stmt->fetch()) 
     {
       array_push($this->grouplist[$functionRun], $username);
     }
```

You want.

```
if($stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query))
  {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $helperVariable);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($username);

    // Inside the If Block
    while ($stmt->fetch()) 
    {
       array_push($this->grouplist[$functionRun], $username);
    }
  }
```

The `while ($stmt->fetch())` can be called on an `$stmt` that may equal `false` or `null`.

Comment: that shouldn't be the problem because it works when i don't call $this->Groups();

Comment: Aside from the simple, test this fix, it maybe that the query prep doesn't fail unless you call groups first.

We have no way of testing or even guessing what MAY be happening. Only you can do this.

Comment: i think its because you can't run the query more than once with the same variable name. Is there a way i can dynamically change the name of the variable query